# Change an object passed by pointer to a function

Tags: c++, pointers

I need:

1. Create reference to object.
2. Pass it to a function that calls the constructor of the object's class and make some calculation over the object.
3. Pass the object to another function that also make some stuff with it.

My object that goes to the second function is always empty.

I slightly know the difference between stack and heap memory and the use of new operator but can't handle with it. I don't understand why `g` doesn't change after the func1 is over.

```
#include <iostream>

class Grid
{
    public:
        int a;

        Grid()
        {
            a = 2;
        }
};

void func1(Grid * g);
void func2(Grid * g);

int
main ()
{
    Grid g;
    func1(&g);
    func2(&g);
}

void
func1 (Grid * g)
{
    g = new Grid();
    g->a = 5;
}

void
func2 (Grid * g)
{
    std::cout << g->a << std::endl;
}
```

How make the output in the func2 5, cause now it's 2?

Comment: This `g = new Grid();` changes the temporary pointer `g`, and not the original object. That's why the value of `Grid::a` remains unchanged. What if you remove this statement: `g = new Grid();`?

Comment: Thanks! Why is this pointer temporary? and how to deal with it?

Comment: It's temporary, as any other function parameter, no matter whether it's a pointer of a value.

Comment: @vahancho: The word "temporary" isn't really accurate here. It's "local". Also a pointer _is_ a value!

Comment: @vahancho Also please don't answer in the comments section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use pointers to "pass by reference", then just do that:

```
void
func1 (Grid * g)
{
    g->a = 5;
}

void
func2 (const Grid * g)
{
    std::cout << g->a << std::endl;
}

int
main ()
{
    Grid g;
    func1(&g);
    func2(&g);
}
```

Currently you're taking a pointer (and remember that the pointer itself is passed by value), then *overwriting* the locally-scoped copy of that pointer with a pointer to a new, dynamically-allocated `Grid` object. You set a property on that object then leak it.

In C++ we often use actual references instead, which can be clearer (though perhaps not as clear at the callsite!):

```
void
func1 (Grid& g)
{
    g.a = 5;
}

void
func2 (const Grid& g)
{
    std::cout << g.a << std::endl;
}

int
main ()
{
    Grid g;
    func1(g);
    func2(g);
}
```

As for this bit:

> Pass it to a function that calls the constructor of the object's class

The object is already constructed. You can copy-assign from a fresh, temporary object if you really want to "reset" it in that way:

```
void
func1 (Grid& g)
{
    g = Grid();
    g.a = 5;
}
```

But I'd advise reconsidering whether you really want/need to reset the object like this. And, if you do, perhaps a nice `reset()` member function?

Comment: You don't compile

Comment: @SombreroChicken Neither does your mum

Comment: But her homemade cookies are quite delicious.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Biscuits!

Comment: SaMe Difference. Colour *color* **flavour** flavor swim swam swum mum mom HELPME

Comment: Ok so I want to apologise, it wasn't crashing due to your code but I think my desktops microchip is faulty.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Classic 

Comment: But what if I obtain the results for constructor only inside func1? That is I can avoid creating an object inside func1?

Comment: @SergeiShumilin You could give your class a `reset()` member function.

Answer (score 3):

here is another possibility using pointers

```
Grid *  func1();
void func2(Grid * g);


int main ()
{

    Grid * g = func1();
    func2(g);
}


Grid * func1 ()
{
    Grid * g = new Grid();
    g->a = 5;
    return g;
}


void func2 (Grid * g)
{
    std::cout << g->a << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Explain your solution. Also you have a memory leak.

Comment: need just to delete the pointer at the end of the program of course, and adding some protection for memory allocation. but the version using reference still the best solution i think.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, when you use `new`, you change the value of the pointer.

But anyway, I think you can do it much more easier. For example:

```
void func(Grid & g)
{
    g.a = 5;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
Of course, you have to call `func()` like this:

```
Grid gr;
func(gr);
```

I hope it can help;

Comment: did you mean to initialize an object here? Like `Grid{}`?

Comment: But what if I obtain the results for constructor only inside func1? That is I can avoid creating an object inside func1?

Comment: @SergeiShumilin When you declare `Grid g;`, you call the default constructor. So you don't need to call the constructor inside `func1()`. But if you want to reset it, you can either call `g = Grid();` inside `func1()` or create a `reset()` member function as @LightnessRacesInOrbit advised to you.

Answer (score 1):

To help you imagine this, I'm going to write it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Grid
{
    public:
        int a;

        Grid()
        {
            a = 2;
        }
};

void func1(uint64_t g);
void func2(uint64_t g);

int
main ()
{
    Grid g;
    func1((uint64_t)&g);
    func2((uint64_t)&g);
}

void
func1 (uint64_t g)
{
    g = (uint64_t)new Grid();
    ((Grid*)g)->a = 5;
}

void
func2 (uint64_t g)
{
    std::cout << ((Grid*)g)->a << std::endl;
}
```

The code above will work exactly the same as the other code (on a 64-bit system). Obviously it is horrific and the code above should never be used, but writing it out like this might help you understand pointers.

Comment: I don't think that hack-casting everything to `uint64_t` is a good way to understand pointers.

Comment: I don't know, it demonstrates that pointers are just numbers like every other variable.

Comment: But they're not.

Comment: Yes they are, a pointer is a number. That number just so happens to be the memory address of another variable, but it is still fundamentally a number.

Comment: No, it is fundamentally a pointer. That they can be represented as numbers is either an implementation detail or an abstraction leak, depending on how you look at it. But pointers are much more restricted than numbers. (Admittedly this is not well-known for some reason.) _Pointers are not numbers; they are pointers._